# Azure Host thresholds exceeded: [Connections] even without function logic

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a function app (v.1) that acts on a DocumentDbTrigger. I can see via appinsights that the Azure Host thresholds exceeded: [Connections] exception is thrown at startup of the instances.

I know that this is can be caused by an HttpClient or DocumentClient that is leaking connections, or creating connections to too many different endpoints (300 is the limit afaik). This doesn't seem to be the issue in this case.

The difficult thing is that the function works well sometimes with hardly any exception. At other times, it can't get anything done because this error is thrown constantly.

I can reproduce the issue even with a function **that has no logic within its body**; it's literally doing nothing.

Some info about the changefeed that it consumes; I'm filling up a cosmosdb collection via ADF copy activity. This works well and my 1.8 million rows get written fast. I created the collection wit 200k ru/s and scale down to 50k ru/s; this yields me 33 partitionkeyranges.

Since this seems to be an on-again, off-again issue, I don't know how to remediate this.

```
    [FunctionName("Stager")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: Documents.Database,
            collectionName: Documents.StagingCollection,
            ConnectionStringSetting = Documents.ConnectionStringName,
            LeaseDatabaseName = Documents.LeaseDatabase,
            LeaseCollectionName = Documents.StagingLeaseCollection,
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true,
            MaxItemsPerInvocation = 25)] JArray input,
        ILogger logger)
    {...}
```

Thanks for any insights that might pop up!

Comment: Can you share your function app name, either here or privately: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: Hi @ConnorMcMahon, Function started (Id=86e9f580-b00c-46da-b533-d8ae85c1d229)